# Diferencia entre VPS y servidor cloud

Tags: linux

Buenas , estoy un tanto confundido en el tema.
Tengo entendido que el VPS es una máquina física al que se le ha dividido en entornos virtuales ,se cobra una tarifa fija y no posee particion swap.

El servidor cloud tiene una infraestructura especial(no se a que se refiere esto) , y abstrae el hardware fisico del servidor(a que se refiere exactamente esto?),tiene particion swap y generalmente es mejor escalable que el vps.

Entre las dudas que he puesto en parentesis, que otras diferencias hay entre estas 2 tecnologías,y si cuando se hace referencia a la computacion en la nube también aplicaría para el caso de las vps.

Pongo el caso de digitalocean en muchos lugares sale que lo llaman servidor vps y otros servidor cloud , hay algún error en la interpretación?

Comment: No me queda claro si son dos tipos de IaaS o uno es IaaS y el otro es PaaS. ¿Puedes aclarar de que proveedor te refieres? Es decir, quien provee el servicio y que servicios estás comparando

Comment: Son muchas preguntas en una sola publicación para el formato de SOes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diferentes proveedores pueden llamar a lo mismo de diferente manera. Cloud server de Digital Ocean es equivalente (mismo tipo de producto) a un VPS de OVH o una instancia de Amazon EC2, son máquinas virtuales alojadas en su infraestructura.

La infraestructura especial se puede entender como un ordenador muy grande (en realidad conjuntos de CPU's, RAM y discos) que el software de orquestación presenta al administrador como un gran conjunto de recursos que divide en máquinas virtuales y presenta a su vez a los clientes. Como si instalas Virtualbox en un ordenador, generas dos máquinas virtuales, le das 2 IP's y cobras a alguien por acceder y usar esas máquinas virtuales.

Creo que no añaden una partición swap porque, dependiendo del software que se vaya a usar, no siempre es recomendable usarla, sobre todo si quieres afinar mucho el rendimiento. Igualmente suele haber guías de los proveedores sobre como añadir swap en sus VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se tiene un servidor VPS se obtiene el mismo servicio del servidor en el que se explotan varios servicios, ahora bien el cloud es mas robusto en su infraestructura y por eso es mas ergonómico en entornos virtuales.

Espero que la breve explicación sirva.

https://youtu.be/SnGCFhQFnLs

Exacto, el cloud a nivel infraestructura es mucho mejor pues son varios clusters, un ejemplo es de que por x o y razón tengas 3 servicios a VPS pero se caiga el servidor sabrás que es culpa del mismo, en cambio si tenes esos mismos 3 servicios en un Cloud sera mas probable que solo uno presente problemas pues por lo general los proveedores ponen los servicios en clusters diferentes.

Comment: Considera agregar un pequeño resumen del video en texto, por si un día el video deja de estar allí, la respuesta siga siendo válida.

Comment: Hola bueno lo que entendi del video esque el VPS es una supercomputadora , y el servidor cloud es un cluster de servidores supongo que usarán algo parecido a RAID ,o que se yo ,y aunque la capacidad individual de c/u es menor la eficiencia global es mayor